# Create a Shapefile datastore in GeoServer using REST API

Tags: shapefile, geoserver-rest-api

I am trying to create a datastore for shapefile in GeoServer using REST API but I am unable to create a datastore for shapefile.

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/cite/datastores

<dataStore>
 <name>Test</name>
  <type>Shapefile</type>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
    <workspace>
    <name>cite</name>
  </workspace>
  <url>file:///home/ubuntu/mapfiles/test/shapefile.shp</url>
</dataStore>

ERROR: 500 Server Error
```

When I follow same procedure for GeoTIFF files everything works fine.

Comment: What does the log file say? What is the command you are using?